# Chrome recording icon stays on even after recording has stopped

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, getusermedia, video-recording, web-mediarecorder

I am using getUserMedia to record using the user's browser:

```
stream.current = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
        echoCancellation: {exact: true}
    },
    video: {
        width: { ideal: 240 }, height: { ideal: 160 }
    }
});

window.stream = stream.current;

let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus'};
try {
    mediaRecorder.current = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
    
    return;
}

mediaRecorder.current.ondataavailable = (event:BlobEvent) => {
    recordedBlobs.current.push(event.data);
    uploadRecordedAnswer(recordedBlobs, mutationAddAttemptAnswer)
}

mediaRecorder.current.start();
```

However, the chrome recording icon does not go away even after I have stopped the recording, like this:

```
// All these does not get rid of the red icon
stream.current!.getTracks().forEach((track:MediaStreamTrack) => track.stop());
console.log(window.stream,window.stream.getTracks())
mediaRecorder.current!.stop()

window.stream.getTracks().forEach((track:MediaStreamTrack) => track.stop());
```

According to other posts the red icon should disappear after ***stream.getTracks().forEach((track:MediaStreamTrack) => track.stop());*** but it still stays there for me. I know that the recording has already stopped because when I check the recorded video it stops after I click stop-recording, but the red icon still does not disappear

FYI I am using react useRef hence the stream.current

Comment: Are you sure you call getUserMedia only once?

Comment: Yes I searched the entire code base to make sure that was the only time I called getUserMedia.

Comment: And you also made sure that whatever function this snippet is in, only gets called once? (You could add a console.log in there and check how many messages there are)

Comment: Yep it is only called once, there is only one console.log message

Answer (score 1):

Firefox detect event with stop but on Chrome required this :

```
 // activeStream?: MediaStream;

 this.activeStream!.getAudioTracks().forEach((track: MediaStreamTrack) => {
        track.stop();
        this.activeStream!.removeTrack(track);
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

peerConnection.close(),Calling this method terminates the RTCPeerConnection's ICE agent, ending any ongoing ICE processing and any active streams.

Comment: But I have never initialised any peerConnection object though, may I know which objectis it thhat I should use this close() method on?

Answer (score -1):

I thinks you just have to release all the reference on the media stream to lose the media indicator on a website, (so it is garbage collected). The MediaRecorder also hold a reference on it.
So a `windows.stream = undefined` should do the work, same for the Recorder.
The indicator will disapear some time after.
Ex:

```
var medias = null;
var rc = null;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then((res)=> {
  medias = res
  rc = new MediaRecorder(res, {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus'});
  rc.start();
  setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("end");
        medias = null; // the indicator will disapear.
        rc.stop();
        rc = null;
      }, 5000);
 });
```

Comment: Does that work in Chrome which (unlike Firefox) won't garbage-collect MediaStreamTracks?

Comment: it work yes. That's how i do in my telephony webapp.

I tested a little more , it seems that the behaviour change if you test the above code directly in the dev console on chrome, if the permissions popup was triggered the indicator is not released , if the grant is automatic it work , a strange case. With a normal script in a html script tag  it seems to work  in any case. 

I will check about garbage and media stream , was not aware of that.

Comment: I tried this:
stream.current = null
window.stream = null
mediaRecorder.current = undefined
but it still won't go away though

Comment: did you also clean the mediaRecorder? 
I update my answer

Comment: This didn't work. The right answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44274928/10676154